# Syntax error on a LEFT JOIN of two tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, jet-sql

I am trying to update a table (HRBI) with a LEFT JOIN on another table. I am getting a syntax area on the following script:

```
UPDATE HRBI 
LEFT JOIN REMMINC ON (HRBI.[PayGroupCountryDesc] = REMMINC.[REMCountry]) AND (HRBI.[BusinessLvl1(Group)Code] = REMMINC.[BusinessGroup]);
```

Is there anything obviously wrong with this? Thanks!

Comment: are you not missing a `set` condition?\

Comment: Yes. I think that will work. I wasn't sure if that was required. Thanks

Comment: @user1813558 You need to have a `SET` declaration otherwise it makes the whole update void and useless.

Answer (score 1):

You currently aren't updating anything.

You need a `set` condition along the lines of:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET SomeColumnName = someValue
WHERE SomeCondition = someOtherValue
```